# Phantom 'padding' after image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm creating a website using the [responsive.gs](http://responsive.gs/) framework.

I've just added some images in a row of containing divs on the [homepage](http://www.haydockoffice.co.uk).

For some reason the images are showing 'padding' at the bottom of them. Chrome Developer tools shows no padding but shows the containing div to be 230px x 239px when it should be 230px x 230px.

I have a feeling it's due to the clearfix method in the responsive.gs CSS because it adds an `:after` element to all of the major elements of the layout. However I've tried, changing to `display:block`, `overflow:hidden`, `padding:0px`, `margin:0px` and no such luck at clearing the 'padding'

```
/* SELF CLEARING FLOATS - CLEARFIX METHOD */
.container:after,
.row:after, 
.col:after, 
.clr:after, 
.group:after { 
    content: ""; 
    display: table; 
    clear: both; 
}
```

Has anyone encountered anything like this before?

Live site is here... http://www.haydockoffice.co.uk/

**CSS for box...**

```
.box {
    background:#f0f;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

**CSS for responsive grid system...**

http://www.haydockoffice.co.uk/assets/css/grid.css

**HTML for boxes...**

```
<div id="homepage" class="row">

    <div id="content" class="row gutters">

        <div class="box col s3">
            <img src="assets/images/products/product1.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div class="box col s3">
            <img src="assets/images/products/product1.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div class="box col s3">
            <img src="assets/images/products/product1.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div class="box col s3">
            <img src="assets/images/products/product1.jpg" />
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**Unwanted effect:**

[image: unwanted padding]

Comment: That margin is meant to be there, it adds spacing between the blocks, its the bottom padding I want to remove.

Comment: Yeah, my bad,  I misread the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `line-height` to 0

```
.box {
   background:#f0f;
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
   line-height:0;
}
```

Before: http://jsfiddle.net/JfMFF/

After: http://jsfiddle.net/JfMFF/1/

Comment: doesn't show any `line-height:0;` to me, removed it? Don't copy the commented out from "Before".

Comment: Sorry you were right, I'd added it to the wrong stylesheet.

Comment: Good, was going nuts and imported more stuff from your CSS already; http://jsfiddle.net/JfMFF/3/ with `display: block` as a alternate solution.

Answer (score 2):

Apply `display: block` to images.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you have already tried display:block but I've just edited the site with inspector and applying display:block to the image removed the padding.

```
<div id="homepage" class="row">

<div id="content" class="row gutters">

    <div class="box col s3">
        <img style="display:block;" src="assets/images/products/product1.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="box col s3">
        <img style="display:block;" src="assets/images/products/product1.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="box col s3">
        <img style="display:block;" src="assets/images/products/product1.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="box col s3">
        <img style="display:block;" src="assets/images/products/product1.jpg" />
    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Just tried this method and this works too, i wasn't adding it to the image, i was adding it to the clearfix method.